# Какие знаки препинания ставить

Tags: пунктуация

1. И я понял, это не просто везение, это судьба. перед всеми "это" ставится запятая или тире?
2. Я с нетерпением жду наших семейных вечеров с обязательной прогулкой перед сном. между "семейных вечеров" и ""с обязательной прогулкой" надо запятую ставить или ничего не надо?

Comment: спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

***И я понял: это не просто везение - это судьба.***
**Двоеточие** ставим по правилам постановки этого знака в бессоюзном сложном предложении. Вторая часть дополняет первую: *И я понял* ЧТО? 
**Тире** подчёркивает противопоставление частей "*это не просто везение - это судьба*".  Это одно из условий постановки ТИРЕ в бессоюзном сложном предложении.

***Я с нетерпением жду наших семейных вечеров с обязательной прогулкой перед сном.***
 Запятая не нужна. ВЕЧЕРОВ каких? С ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОЙ ПРОГУЛКОЙ ПЕРЕД СНОМ. Распространённое несогласованное определение. Показаний к обособлению нет.

Но справедливости (или истины) ради надо сказать, что обособление несогласованного распространённого  определения ВОЗМОЖНО [Об этом здесь](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_2_3_4)

Answer (score 0):

1. Во-первых, после слова "понял" хорошо бы поставить двоеточие, а не тире. А вот во втором случае, мне кажется, тут можно и занятую, и тире — по желания автора.
2. Нет, здесь запятая не нужна, тут ведь нет перечисления.